# Java WebSocket. WebSocketSession id

Tags: java, spring, websocket

In my project, I use webSocket. When the user goes from one page to another, webSocket closes, then when returning to the same page, the webSocketSession id changes (adding 1). The webSocketSession id is int and now I am concerned that when I run the project, the webSocketSession id will exceed the maximum size of int.

Comment: can you please add the configuration of your WebSocket.? And is it spring or spring-boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table that follows you can see that the range of int in Java is 2.147.483.647. I do not believe that you would have a problem with using int.

But for your convenience you might want to change the int to long, as you can see the max value is much much higher.

If for any reason you insist to keep on using int, maybe after a point that the user browses you can find a way to zero the index of int so it can start over or you can set the start of the index at -2 147 483 648 so you can double your index.

```
          width                     minimum                         maximum

SIGNED
byte:     8 bit                        -128                            +127
short:   16 bit                     -32 768                         +32 767
int:     32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
long:    64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807

UNSIGNED
char     16 bit                           0                         +65 535
```